# Some files got locked in perforce checklist automatically.

Tags: perforce, code-collaborator

How some files got locked in perforce checklist automatic. That checklist was having some files, some random files got locked. it was on the review. I am not getting, How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to a submit starting and then not completing.  Files are locked at the start of a submit in order to make sure that no other changes are made while the submit is in progress; if the submit fails, the files stay locked so that the submitting user can fix the problem and try again before anyone else submits new revisions that they will need to resolve.

The owner of the changelist can choose to unlock the files (they will be unlocked automatically if the files are either reverted or submitted), or an admin can force the unlock with "p4 unlock -f".